# gmaps - find locations within visible area

Tags: mysql, google-maps, geolocation

I'm trying to develop a function that gets all relevant records within the currently visible area.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html

I found this tutorial (and got it to work) to get locations within a radius which helped a lot but i would need it to be exactly within the visible part (rectangle).

Any idea how that works?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Alright i found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834772/get-all-records-from-mysql-database-that-are-within-google-maps-getbounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current visible area can be determined by the [Map objects getBounds() method](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map).  If you have a list of points or lat/longs, you can use MySQL to query this, providing the bounds returned from the map.  You can also use [Fusion Tables to store your data instead of MySQL](http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2010/05/fusion-tables-google-maps-api.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=feed%3a+googlemapsmania+%28google+maps+mania%29) and [use its relatively new Geo methods](http://www.google.com/support/fusiontables/bin/topic.py?topic=27020).