# Get items between latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

I stored the latitude and longitude from a lot of gasstations in a database. I also made a Google Maps. Now, I want to select the gasstations from my database where latitude and longitude are between the North East Latitude / Longitude and South West Latitude / Longitude from my Google Maps.

How can i calculate which gasstations I have to select?

Comment: possible duplicate of [inside lat,lng bounds where query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214519/inside-lat-lng-bounds-where-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply modify your database query in the backend to only return locations between your points. Something like the [first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834772/get-all-records-from-mysql-database-that-are-within-google-maps-getbounds).

Obviously the syntax will depend on the database that you are using.

Actually I would suggest using:

```
SELECT * FROM tilistings WHERE lat BETWEEN a AND c AND lng between b AND  d
```

Where a and b are you top left coordinates and c and d are your bottom right. I think BETWEEN is more performant.